# Automate of mRemoteNG using C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, mremoteng

I am working on C# Winform application. The requirement is to open Remote Desktop Window without user interaction. For this I have saved remote Host IP, username and password in database.
On button click I am executing below command  and it is working fine.

```
generic:"<server>" /user:"<user>" /pass:"<pass>"
```

**Problem with this approach :** The problem is title of Remote Desktop Window. It just shows IP Address but users wants machine name instead of IP Address in Title. I am not able to find anything which can change title of Remote Desktop Window.

I found mRemoteNG can show different Title instead of IP Address. I am trying to automate mRemoteNG from my application. mRemoteNG uses one connection xml to open Remote Desktop. mRemoteNG has command line options to provide path of connections.xml file and based on connections.xml it will open the remote desktop window. The connection.xml file contains different parameters and password in **encrypted** format. Due to this I am not able to generate connections.xml from my own.

**Problem:** I am not able to find any library which can generate connection xml file for mRemoteNG.

I need help how to automate mRemoteNG for this situation.

Comment: why use ip instead of server name then?

Comment: question modified. User want to connect machine with that IP Address. All remote machines are on other network. A tunnel is created between 2 network and through this tunnel remote machine is connected.